# How can I cast a Text attribute to an integer for a RangeValidator using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, casting, attributes

I'm obviously new to ASP.Net, but I have a quick question.

I have text boxes and labels for forms on the main page. One of the text boxes is a wager amount. But since the input is a text box, I keep getting errors when trying to pass one of the other text box ID's (stake) to the RangeValidator.

To clear that up.. I need the **RangeValidator** for **wager** to be between 1 and **stake**. Since obviously a wager can't be more than the stake.

I tried using CInt(currentstake.Text) and some other things, but it seems like it's stuck as a string/text type.

Here's an example of what I've been trying to do:

```
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" ControlToValidate="wager" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid wager." MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="CInt(currentstake.Text)" Type="Integer" runat="server"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Any easy way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using CustomValidation you can create a custom function javascript or in the server that check if the value is correct, so you can see t[his article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information

Other option si to use an CompareValidator but doesn't work for range, you could also validate that the value is less than currentstake. So:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" 
   runat="server" 
   ControlToCompare="currentstake" 
   ControlToValidate="wager" 
   Operator="LessThan" 
   ErrorMessage="Wrong Value" 
   SetFocusOnError="True">
```

Comment: Thanks. This is supposed to be an introduction to ASP.Net and supposably can be done without javascript customizations. I'm looking for a quick fix, but I'll look at that just in case.

Comment: I update my answer to show an alternative with CompareValidator

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I totally agree :)

Comment: Ohhh okay that makes sense, Thanks! I actually found a cheat way of doing it in the vb file. I used:  If Int32.TryParse(wager.Text, wagerAmount) Then
            wagerAmount = CInt(wager.Text). It works, but definitely not the most efficient way of doing it. I'll keep this was of doing it noted for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the most flexible validator type. Here's a complete sample with a client- and servervalidation function incl. validation-groups:

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Wager" runat="server" ValidationGroup="WagerVG"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Stake" runat="server" ValidationGroup="WagerVG"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:CustomValidator ValidationGroup="WagerVG" ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
     OnServerValidate="WagerValidation" 
     ClientValidationFunction="WagerValidation_CV"
     ValidateEmptyText="true" 
     ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid wager." 
     ForeColor="Red">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="SubmitWager" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="WagerVG" runat="server" />
```

javascript validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WagerValidation_CV(sender, e) {
        var valid = false;
        var txtWager = document.getElementById('<%= Wager.ClientID %>');
        var txtStake = document.getElementById('<%= Stake.ClientID %>');
        if (txtWager != null && txtStake != null) {
            var wager = parseInt(txtWager.value);
            var stake = parseInt(txtStake.value);
            valid = wager >= 1 && wager <= stake;
        }
        e.IsValid = valid;
    }
</script>
```

servervalidation-function:

```
protected void WagerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    bool valid = true;
    int wager, stake;
    if (!int.TryParse(Wager.Text, out wager))
        valid = false;
    if (!int.TryParse(Stake.Text, out stake))
        valid = false;
    valid = valid && wager >= 1 && wager <= stake;
    args.IsValid = valid;
}
```

A `CustomValidator` is typically used if multiple controls are dependent of each other. Remember to set `ValidateEmptyText="true"` to force validation even with empty textboxes and to omit the `ControlToValidate` to force validation on both controls.

**Edit**: another option is to use a combination of two `CompareValidators` and two `RequiredFieldValidators`(if you want to prevent empty texts):

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="WagerVG"
    ControlToValidate="Wager" ControlToCompare="Stake" 
    Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Integer" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a value greater 0 and less or equal stake">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="WagerVG"
    ControlToValidate="Wager" ValueToCompare="1"
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Integer" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a value greater 0 and less or equal stake">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```